# How to get total record count for records that match 3 different criteria in single query

Tags: sql

I have a table similar to this

```
    Item1     Item2
    yes        yes
    yes        no
    yes        yes
    yes        yes
```

etc., etc.

I need to get  the count of the records that have both Item1 & Item2. And also the counts for records that just have Item1 or Item2 and not have duplicate records in the final query. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want `group by`:

```
select item1, item2, count(*)
from t
group by item1, item2;
```

If you specifically want to combine values, you could do:

```
select sum(case when item1 = 'yes' and item2 = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as two_yesses,
      sum(case when (item1 = 'yes' or item2 = 'yes') and item1 <> item2
               then 1 else 0
          end) as one_yes
from t;
```